# How to add checkbox option to electron app installer which is using electron-builder

Tags: javascript, electron, nsis, electron-builder

I'm developing an electron app, which is using electron-builder to create an executable (.exe) file of my application, now my question is, how can I add a checkbox to this installer which is going to be responsible for installing python.exe on the computer, because the electron app is using some python script to gather data, so I want when user install electron app to give him the option to install python dependency if checkbox is checked. I saw that I need some custom NSIS scripts, but I'm not familiar with that, I have tried some examples but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this, it is not best but it's working.

I have created `installer.nsh` like bellow:

```
!macro customInstall
  ExecWait '$INSTDIR\resources\dependencies\python-3.11.1.exe /repair /quiet 
  InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1'
  ExecWait 'py -m pip install pythonnet'
!macroend
```

I moved installer.nsh into  assets, you can move it wherever you want.
After that I have added folder dependencies and in here I have added all dependencies that needs to be installed. In my case it is python-3.11.1.exe installer.

Now to include this dependencies folder you have to se extraResources in package.json like this:

```
"extraResources": [
  "./assets/**",
  "./dependencies"
],
```

This will include your folder when you run build package.
After this you have to configure your nsis in package.json file to include your installer.nsh in installation, see bellow:

```
"nsis": {
  "menuCategory": true,
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true,
  "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "runAfterFinish": false,
  "include": "assets/installer.nsh"
}
```

With all of this wrapped additional command at the end of installation will be triggered and also you can run some pip installation like in installer.nsh example.